Webpage gets rendered differently across different mobile browsers with meta viewport tags
I have a webpage that gets rendered on Android browsers different than on iOS browsers.
When we have this meta tag
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=yes">, it works just fine on Android devices fully zoomed out and the DOM elements fitting the device width zoomed out on default. However, it gets messed up on the iOS devices, as it gets rendered zoomed in even though I'm specifying the witdh=device-width, also I tried many different solutions that none worked fine on both devices till now.
What worked fine on iOS is randomly, this <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; maximum-scale=5">, I know it's weird with the semicolon instead of the comma separator, but this works fine on iOS and renders the view correctly, but it messes the android rendering.
Any clue what is wrong here?

Did you try width=device-width, initial-scale=1 ?
